# listening to change in variable values and handling click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

For the first 3 secs the variable x has value 0 and after 3 secs the x value is set to 1.

Whenever we click the button in between 0 and 3 secs, function handleClick should not be called.
Whenever we click the button in after 3 secs, function handleClick should be called.

Below is the HTML and JS code that i am using. But the function handleClick is not called even after 3 secs.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="quizy-mg-item">click here</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var x=0;
setTimeout(3000,function(){
x=1 
})
function handleClick(){
document.write("Success");
}
if(x) {
$('.quizy-mg-item').click(handleClick);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.quizy-mg-item').click(handleClick);
},3000);

function handleClick(){
  document.write("Success");
}
```

Your setTimeout function's order of argument was wrong.

Also here,

```
if(x) {
  $('.quizy-mg-item').click(handleClick);
}
```

At the time of condition check inside `if`, `x` is actually 0, hence no `click` handler is attached. It has nothing to do with value of `x` later.

p.s. Dont use `document.write` , use `console.log` to debug.

Comment: No `setTimeout` fires only once. Its `setInterval` that gets called after every specified period.